# Disable dropup feature using Bootstrap Select

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, select, bootstrap-select

I'm using Bootstrap Select to style some select fields inside an accordion. Bootstrap select has a feature where it will make your dropdown dropup if it is near the bottom of the screen.

In this case I do not want it to drop up but I can't find where to disable this.

Bootstrap select: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Options can be passed via JavaScript or data attributes:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    dropupAuto: false
});
```

or

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-dropup-auto="false">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

You can also set this globally:

```
$.fn.selectpicker.Constructor.DEFAULTS.dropupAuto = false;
```

Comment: Except you don't want quotes around 'false'. It needs to be boolean. :)

Comment: I tried all these and still cannot stop it from dropping up and when it drops up it is hidden behind the navbar.

Comment: @GrahamHesketh What version are you using?

Comment: v1.13.0 I need it to be compatible with bootstrap 4

Comment: Where is camelCase in JS, there is dash and lowercase in `data-` attribute. So `dropupAuto` became `data-dropup-auto`, `selectedTextFormat` is `data-selected-text-format`... etc  Good to know :)  
See [all options](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/options/#core-options) in documentation.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in v1.13.10, anyone know why?

Comment: yea still not working

Answer (score 2):

This setting can be changed in the bootstrap-select.js file by editing the dropupAuto option to:

dropupAuto: false,

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to disable the picker.
$('.selectpicker').prop('disabled', true);

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.  The OP wants to stop the Bootstrap Select control from dropping upwards as opposed to downwards so that it always drops down, and never up.