# Bootstrap-select always opening down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootrap-select (https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) to display my dropdowns.

When there not enough space down, dropdown are displayed up.

[image]

Instead, I would like to force the opening Always down, like this:

[image]

Is it possible to force dropdown to opening Always down?

Comment: [Check it here for the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934518/disable-dropup-feature-using-bootstrap-select)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can help you:

please try this and see fiddle link:

```
<div class="container">
    <select class="select-picker" id="picker1" data-size="10">
        <option>Opt 1</option>
        <option>Opt 2</option>
        <option>Opt 3</option>
        <option>Opt 4</option>
    </select>

    <select class="select-picker" id="picker2" data-size="10">
        <option>Opt 2.1</option>
        <option>Opt 2.2</option>
        <option>Opt 2.3</option>
        <option>Opt 2.4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u6vWL/116/

Answer (score 2):

Just answering here as it gets appear  in google search

Link to original [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934518/disable-dropup-feature-using-bootstrap-select)

---

Options can be passed via JavaScript or data attributes:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    dropupAuto: false
});
```

or

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-dropup-auto="false">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

You can also set this globally:

```
$.fn.selectpicker.Constructor.DEFAULTS.dropupAuto = false;
```