# Disable drop up on Rails form - bootstrap

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to prevent Bootstrap's automatic drop up from occurring on smaller screen sizes.

The S.O. question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934518/disable-dropup-feature-using-bootstrap-select) says to add to add the attribute `data-dropup-auto` and set it to `false`, however upon doing so it doesn't work. Inspecting the select drop down from the Chrome developer console also reveals the attribute to be present and correctly set to false.

Here is the code for my select in the form.

```
<%= f.select(:countries_id_eq, Country.order(:name).collect{|c| [c.name,c.id]}, {:prompt => "Exam Cycle"}, { :class => 'form-control input-lg', "data-dropup-auto" => "false" }) %>
```

In the developer console, the select renders like this

```
<select class="form-control input-lg" id="q_universities_id_eq" name="q[universities_id_eq]" data-dropup-auto="false"><option value="">Subjects</option>...</select>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean to link another SO question? Also, go to the rendered HTML page and paste here what the `select` looks like.

Comment: @nicholas79171 I've added in both now.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20503446/3251199), you need to remove the quotes around the attribute value since it's boolean.

```
<%= f.select(:countries_id_eq, Country.order(:name).collect{|c| [c.name,c.id]}, {:prompt => "Exam Cycle"}, { :class => 'form-control input-lg', "data-dropup-auto" => false }) %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nicholas - I saw that comment as well and tried it but unfortunately it resulted in the same behaviour with the drop-downs becoming drop-ups on smaller screen sizes.

Comment: Have you tried editing the default value in the `bootstrap-select.js` file? For me it's on line 298. Setting that to false should do it.

Comment: I have, still the same behaviour unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the setting using JavaScript like in the answer I linked to?

Comment: I have - This however adds the bootstrap class of `select-picker` to my select element which alters the appearance of the element. It does however fix the issue.

Comment: That's the problem. `select-picker.js` looks for `select` items that are tagged with the class `select-picker`. Otherwise, it doesn't know which `select` tags you want to edit. Add `select-picker` to your `select` and it will solve your issue. You'll have to use more CSS or JS to fix the style changes.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas - I was thinking that myself but I thought there may have been a more elegant way to tackle this issue. I'll go with that though. If you post an answer I'll give you the green tick :)