# Make bootstrap dropdown menu go only downwards?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-select, bootstrap-4

i have a little problem with my Bootstrap Select Box on the following

[Website](http://www.deadstock.de/releases/)

As you might notice while scrolling the page up and down its disturbing the dropdown opens to both sides up/down.

Now i am not sure if this might be a bug or standard functionality of the Bootstrap Select.

Preview:
[image: See here]

How i am able to fix this to only opens downwards?

thanks for your kind help in advance.

Comment: Its working properly here on my PC when I tested it. It is opening downwards not up..

Comment: You must be an exception. Lots of users complained about it. However i think with data-dropup-auto="false" its now correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable dropup feature using Bootstrap Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934518/disable-dropup-feature-using-bootstrap-select)

Comment: In the bootstrap 4 dropdown component you need data-flip="false"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Options can be passed via javascript

```js
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    dropupAuto: false
});
```

or

by HTML tag

```html
<select class="selectpicker" data-dropup-auto="false">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```