# Select box options overlapping on browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

In my project, I have one select box and for that select box, options are adding dynamically using angular js. When I resize the browser and open the select box it is overlapping with the browser.

What is the solution for this?

> See the below screenshot

[image: The reference link]

Comment: you can give height of the select option

Comment: how can we set the height of select option? and is there any possibility to set the height of select box dropdown.

Comment: paste your html code

Comment: if you are using bootstrap dropdown then this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45959649/make-bootstrap-dropdown-menu-go-only-downwards